# Taking current location of user and showing products of shops in specified radius

Tags: android

making an e-commerce app to take the current location of the user and radius of search as input and show products of shops listed in the given radius. don,t want the user to see the location of shops.

Comment: So what's the question? And what do you mean with `listed`? Listed where?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.